# Checking whether nested/hierarchy of properties are null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, if-statement

I have:

```
label.Text = myObject.myNestedObject.MyNestedObject2.Description;
```

Where label is asp.net label. The problem is that sometimes myObject, myNestedObject, MyNestedObject2 or Description is null and I must check it in if statement which looks like:

```
if(myObject!=null&&myNestedObject!=null&&MyNestedObject2!=null&&Description!=null)
{
label.Text = myObject.myNestedObject.MyNestedObject2.Description;
}
```

In this statement I check four times whether properties is null. Does  exist any other way to check entire hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[C# null-conditional operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn986595.aspx) to the rescue!

Taken from the MSDN site:

```
int? length = customers?.Length; // null if customers is null 
Customer first = customers?[0];  // null if customers is null
int? count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();  // null if customers, the first customer, or Orders is null
```

Comment: I think it's a good answer for new versions of .net framework but I am using .Net 4.5 in my project and unfortunately this usefull option does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no equivalent to the new null-conditional operators in older versions of the languages.  Note there is a HUGE difference between .NET Framework versions and Language (C#) versions.  You can use VS2015 and the newer C# language features and still target .NET 4.5.